# Create an attribute for a category in Magento programmatically

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

How to create an attribute Magento category programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

your answer is already here just search properly

[create custom category attributes dynamically in admin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8537/create-custom-category-attributes-dynamically-in-admin)